# Puppet refuses to unzip archive

Tags: puppet

I want to download several libraries (guzzle, pimple) and unzip them immediately after.
For guzzle it works without any problems, however it refuses to unzip pimple and returns following error:

> Exec[unflate-pimple]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: tar
>   -zvxf pimple-v1.1.1-0.tar.gz returned 2 instead of one of [0]

My exec:

```
exec {
        "unflate-$lib_name":
            cwd     => "/var/www/lib/$lib_name",
            command => "tar -zvxf $lib_name-$lib_version_prefix$lib_version.tar.gz",
            path   => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
            require => Exec["download-$lib_name"]
    }
```

Where

```
$lib_name = "pimple"
$lib_version_prefix = "v"
$lib_version = "1.1.1-0"
```

Unzipping it manually in the terminal when connecting through SSH works fine.

I already tried unzipping and zipping it again.

I feel completely lost, where is the problem?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: Yes but it was actually a puppet unrelated solution, too long ago to remember it though

Answer (score 1):

To debug this kind of misbehavior, add the `logoutput => true` parameter to the exec resource.

```
exec {
    "unflate-$lib_name":
        cwd     => "/var/www/lib/$lib_name",
        command => "tar -zvxf $lib_name-$lib_version_prefix$lib_version.tar.gz",
        path   => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
        require => Exec["download-$lib_name"],
        logoutput => true,
}
```

Newer versions of Puppet default to `on_error`, which would be fine for your case, too.

The agent will then add the output of `tar` to the log. I cannot debug this for you further without seeing that output, but I suspect you will be able to solve the issue on your own once you see it.